# Product term as interaction only in 'special circumstances'

Tags: regression, interaction, terminology, splines

In an online [post](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/14628gq3ad/r-smoothed-hr-for-interaction-term-in-coxph-model), T. Therneau (author of R survival package) writes "For continuous variables the use of "*" in a formula adds the product of the
two terms, which is not an interaction except in very special circumstances".

What is the interpretation of this statement? Given that adding a product term is the most common method to introduce interactions, does the comment imply that this common method assumes a 'very special circumstance'.

Comment: Can you clarify why you tagged "splines?" Though Maarten may have guessed correctly already...

Comment: I tagged splines because this was the example given by Therneau, but also because this may be the situation where "interaction" takes on a more generalized meaning. I don't think I was missing some common usage of the language, but was curious when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious person to ask is Therneau. I suspect that this has to do with the specific application he discusses, some software that estimates a smooth curve. There is no guarantee that such software recognizes a `*` as an interaction, and this may cause problems. For example if this particular program internally creates a number of additional variables to capture the non-linearity, and it does not recognize `*` as an interaction, then only some of the necessary terms are created. So in the very specific situation he discusses the `*` means an interaction in only very special circumstances (presumably the smooth curve happens to be a straight line). However, in general interaction terms are made by creating products of variables. So I suspect that it means that it depends on the program and how it parses `*`.